# Drop down menu CSS query

Tags: css, submenu

I am styling a drop down menu and the sub-menu is the standard vertical list with left aligned text. I want the last 2 menu items to have right aligned text otherwise they go off the edge of the screen as the sub-menu text is longer than the menu text.

CSS:

```
.menu               {width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: center;}
.menu ul            {display: none;}
.menu li            {display: inline-block; position: relative;}
.menu li a          {display: block; font-size: 12px; color: #fff; height: 50px; line-height: 50px; padding: 0 22px;}
.menu li a:hover        {background: #34556c;}
.menu li:hover ul       {display: block; position: absolute; top: 100%; left: 0; background: #426985; padding-bottom: 5px;}
.menu li ul li          {display: block;}
.menu li ul li a        {height: 20px; line-height: 20px; padding: 3px 85px 3px 20px; white-space: nowrap; text-align: left; }
.menu li#menu-item-133:hover ul, .menu li#menu-item-140:hover ul    {right: 0;}
.menu li#menu-item-133 ul li a, .menu li#menu-item-140 ul li a      {text-align: right; padding: 3px 20px 3px 85px;}
```

This doesn't seem to work as the submenu seems to start at left: 0 and finishes at right: 0, it doesn't overflow left for the text to fit.

Can be seen here: http://tinyurl.com/loamosd (disguised URL as it's clients server's IP).

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had to reset the original left: 0 using left: initial; as well as adding right: 0;